# Keyword based searching and Query Cleaning

Tags: sql-server, database, search, full-text-search, keyword-search

I am implementing a keyword based search for my website. My database contains 5 relations: image,audio,videos,document and otherFiles. Each of them contain name,description,file size and some other information about the file. To implement the keyword based search i am making an index table which basically contains two columns (keywordString,rowId) where 'keywordString' is concatenation of all the columns of type string of a particular row and 'rowId' is the row number from which the column data was taken(basically a pointer to a row in any of the 5 relations). For eg.("key1 key2 key3","imgR1") would mean that row 1 in image table contains the words "key1", "key2", "key3" in any of the columns. 
I just wanna know if this would be scalable when the number of rows in each relation increase to over say 100,000 or more or is there a better way to do this?

Also what sorta words should i remove from the search query? I am definitely removing all duplicate words,articles and conjunctions.

Comment: What RDBMS?  The problem with this approach is that you won't be able to use an index for anything but the first word in the column (that, and multi-value columns are evil).  If you really want to spin stuff out like this, doing a separate row for each key would like be better (but obviously take more space).  Otherwise, some sort of 'tag' setup may work... I think we want more details though; how are you actually using this now (can we get a sample)?

Comment: the keywordString column will be of type varchar(100-100 something) and i will be using the ms sql contains/containstable/freetextsearch/freetext keyword to do the actual search in the index table i create(the search will be done on just that one column). i havent really implemented it yet. i wanted to know if i am heading the right way before i actually started coding. Also i am putting all the required column value from the tables in my database to one column as otherwise i would have to use the contains/containstable/freetextsearch multiple times for each column which i want to avoid.